# React async and await throwing error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined'

Tags: reactjs, rest, asynchronous, async-await

I have this bit of code

```
async makeRestCall() {
    var api = await PrognApi(this.state.Name);
    console.log(api);
  }
```

but react is throw this

Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

in the console. I know I've used async and await before with React but I can't remember how I think I had to install a library. Any advice would be great. I'm using a js file to hold my jsx. I'm using webpack and babel as well.

Comment: Did you try to run `npm install @babel/runtime`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "regeneratorRuntime" is, so maybe the problem is elsewhere. But I saw a few things.

First, it looks like you're missing the opening bracket for your method:

```js
async makeRestCall() {
  var api = await PrognApi(this.state.Name);
  console.log(api);
}
```

Second, is `Name` with a capital "N" correct?

Third, I wonder if your method has the `this` context? Maybe it's having trouble accessing your component's `state`. You could try changing it to an arrow function:

```js
makeRestCall = async () => {
  var api = await PrognApi(this.state.Name);
  console.log(api);
};
```

I don't feel like I have enough information to troubleshoot this. Maybe update your question to show the entire component?

Good luck!

Comment: I tried using arrow function and webpack complained

ERROR in ./components/ProgressionModal.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: X:/tconline/Services/TCAdminTool/TCAdminServer/Scripts/react/components/ProgressionModal.js: Unexpected token (56:15)

  54 |   }
  55 |
> 56 |   makeRestCall = async () => {
     |                ^

Comment: You can bind the `this` context in the constructor: `this.makeRestCall = this.makeRestCall.bind(this);`. (Read more [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56))

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I need Babel-polyfill